# Enable external users access to WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms

I would like some external users to be able to access WMS-services from my internally enabled GeoServer. By opening up my firewall for this specific IP-address it should get access to my WMS-services, right?  I'm sure I'm missing something crucial here since this is new to me.

Is there any other settings/permissions to be set in GeoServer for this specific layer/store/workspace to work out properly? The URL is working fine in internal applications.

Comment: Consider blocking the access to web UI in the firewall https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/web/. It is secured by username/password but having no access is safer. Same thing with REST API access.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know if an external user consuming one of my WMS-services has to fill in usernamn/password by default?

Comment: Services do not require authentication by default. Example: https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other settings/permissions to be set in GeoServer for this specific layer/store/workspace to work out properly?

No, by default it's open to all.